# How to connect audio to MediaStream from youtube iFrame

Tags: javascript, audio, youtube, audiocontext, mediastream

Is it possible to connect audio from a youtube video playing in an iFrame to MediaStream in js AudioContext (to create a visualiser for the audio)?

Alternatively, is there a way to capture and stream audio playing on the webpage to a MediaStream?